# How to add a new column to every model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

with what migration can I add a column to every model at once? This would be handy almost every time you forgot to add a field anyway because most of the time a field you want to add is not limited to one model only. Like "email" In this case I forgot to add an "order" field.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do as follows -

```
def change
  tables = [:users, :products, :addresses]

  tables.each do |table_name|
    add_column table_name, :order, :integer
  end
end
```

It's called a group migration

Answer (score 2):

Answering your first question *"With what migration can I add a column to every model at once?"*. Answer: None. Rails migrations are a way to alter database schemas over time in a consistent way.

Rails migrations are Ruby classes using Rails methods as instructions to modify your database as needed. So your question could be better formulated as *"How can I create a migration to add a column to every model at once?"*

IMHO I don't think there's going to be a specific method to do this, as the requeriment is pretty custom, but, depending in your Rails version you can get all the `ApplicationRecord.descendants`:

```
Zeitwerk::Loader.eager_load_all
ApplicationRecord.descendants.map { |table| table.name.downcase.pluralize }.each do |table|
  add_column table, :logdate, :datetime
end
```

Or all those tables from the database that can be *safe_constantized*:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.map do |table|
  table.classify.safe_constantize
end.reject(&:nil?).each do |table|
  add_column table, :logdate, :datetime
end
```

That way you get the name of each table/model and use it as the first argument for `add_column`.

The difference is that in Rails 6 the default code loader is Zeitwerk, so you can eager load all the project dependencies. In other versions you could do the same but using `Rails.application.eager_load!`.

The second version would work without having to load the models as dependencies as it makes a query asking for their tables and then maps them as constants.